# Handle alerts in selenium webdriver for nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium, automated-tests, xss

I am running a simple webserver in nodejs. On the server side i want to check if the user was successful in getting an alert box in the UI. Could be (confirm , prompt etc) . The payload is in the URL. To check this i create a URL and pass it to selenium to check if it creates an alert box. However, all my attempts to handle the alert are failing with an exception. Heres my code

```
/* global */
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')
const chrome    = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome')
var options   = new chrome.Options();
options.addArguments('headless');
var path = require('chromedriver').path;
let driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome', 'alertBehavior': 'IGNORE'}).
    setChromeOptions(options).
    build();

   /* do bunch of stuff */

function checkXSS(payload) {
    console.log('checking payload')
    var url = 'http://<url>?payload=' + payload
    driver.get(url). //exception thrown here itself. 
    driver.switchTo().alert().then(function() {
      driver.switchTo().alert().accept();},
     function(){});
    }
```

And i get the below exception

```
UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : XSS}
```

I tried other ways too that were suggested on stackoverflow. Such as using driver.get.then(_, =>), alert.dismiss() etc however all of them still throw the same exception. What am i missing here?

Comment: This might be of interest to you: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718235 Specifically the last comment.

Comment: Tried with firefox, same result. it throws an exception, how do i handle it ? is it cause its in the get request itself ?